# Redux saga - the point to skip API requsts if data already exists in redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am working on the project with usage of redux-saga and I have one question to ask you. I tried to find an answer on my question nearly for two days with power of Google but it did not help.

We have some function that is triggered by saga on each FETCH_REQUEST action.

```
export function* fetchData(action) {
  try {
    const usersList = (yield select()).usersList;

    // makes API call only if there is no users found in the current state
    if(!usersList) {
      const data = yield call(Api.fetchUser)
    }

    yield put({type: "FETCH_SUCCEEDED", usersList})
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({type: "FETCH_FAILED", error})
  }
}
```

On success the FETCH_SUCCEEDED action is triggered and we save received data to the state. But it seems to me that the decision making point "to make or not the API call" is not in the right place.
The current approach causes spawning of some amount of actions that are useless and skipped in sagas. In case when some others sagas subscribed on the _REQUEST actions they triggers another useless actions and so on.

So the question is - What is the 'best practice' place to check whether the data needs to be loaded from API or ReduxStore?

Comment: Did you have got a satisfying answer to this problem statement? I am stuck with the same problem and confused about where to handle this case. I see a few limitations in handling in component because there might be lots of components having this use case. Selector is meant for that but again somewhere I have read that selector should be pure function and so on...

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you dispatch `FETCH_REQUEST` action creator from your component. This component probably receives `userList` as a property. So this component is the best place to determine whether `FETCH_REQUEST` action should be dispatched.

Something like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.props.userList) {
      this.props.fetchData();
    }
  }
}

...

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

In this case you don't need to use a selector and extra condition in your saga.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am 100% with you. With a little upgrade that we have HOC with loadData() function that triggers all ..._REQUEST actions. To my mind the loadData() is the best place for the decision making. Can you point me to some thoughts when the current approach of making decisions in Saga is an 'anti-pattern'?

Comment: In a typical web app on the fetch request action we set `loading` flag and display a loading indicator. Then, on FETCH_SUCCEEDED or FETCH_FAILED we set `loading` flag to false. So dispatching FETCH_REQUEST action without actual fetch would cause the permanent display of loading indicator in UI.

Comment: All the things happens so quickly that react batches the updates of UI and loader icon does not blinks at all. Also I must admit that in current project we consider that the data in `loading` phase if the `redux-state` element is `undefined` and omit the `isLoading` flag. Is this good or bad practice?